# Reduce the execution time utilizing two apis

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, json, xml

I am new to python. I have been given a task to verify the data from 2 apis which give similar data but in different format i.e. Json and XML. I have written the code but it is taking too much time to execute. I am unfamiliar with formatting and etc so please help me here. (I am excluding urls and header etc. for security purpose)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import json
import urllib.request
import requests

wb = load_workbook("CNIC.xlsx")
source = wb["Sheet1"]
for cniclist in source['A']:
    cnic = cniclist.value
    url = "/%s" % cnic
    urlobj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    try:
        string = urlobj.read().decode('utf-8')
        json_obj = json.loads(string)
    except:
        print(urlobj.readlines())
    url2 = "url2"
    payload = "<CUSTNO>{}</CUSTNO>"
    headers = {}
    response = requests.request("POST", url2, data=payload.format(cnic), headers=headers)
    tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(response.text))

    json_message = (json_obj.get('Message'))
    if json_message == "Success":

        json_record = (json_obj.get('Records'))
        if json_record == 1:
            for item in json_obj.get('OutData'):
                json_acc = item.get('Accounts')['NoAccounts']
                print("No Of Accounts in Json Service is ", json_acc)

        elif json_record > 1:
            json_acc = 0
            for item in json_obj.get('OutData'):
                json_acc = item.get('Accounts')['NoAccounts']
                print("No Of Accounts in Json Service is ", json_acc)
        else:
            print("No JSON Records found")
        root = tree.getroot()
        count = 0
        xml_acc_no = []
        for FCDB_BODY in root.findall("./FCDB_BODY/CUSTACCOUNT/ACCOUNT/ACCNO"):
            temp = FCDB_BODY.text
            xml_acc_no.append(temp)
            count += 1
        print("No Of Accounts in XML Service is ", str(count))

        # Checking Number of Accounts in both services
        if str(json_acc) == str(count):
            print("Number of Accounts are same in both services")
        elif str(json_acc) > str(count):
            print("Json Service has more accounts  ")
        else:
            print("XML Service has more accounts ")

        # Getting all data from Json Service
        for item1 in json_obj.get('OutData'):
            json_file_account = item1.get('Accounts')[
                'AccountList']  # Getting Accountlist details from jason service file

            json_accounts_list = []
            for i in json_file_account:
                json_acc_no = i['ACC#']  # Getting Account Number from Json service file
                json_accounts_list.append(json_acc_no)

            json_title_list = []
            for i in json_file_account:
                json_acc_title = i['TITLE']  # Getting Account title from Json service file
                json_title_list.append(json_acc_title)

            json_type_list = []
            for i in json_file_account:
                json_account_type = i['STYPE']  # Getting Account type from Json service file
                json_type_list.append(json_account_type)

            json_desc_list = []
            for i in json_file_account:
                json_account_desc = i['STPDESC']  # Getting Account description from Json service file
                if json_account_desc is not "":
                    json_desc_list.append(json_account_desc)
                else:
                    pass
            json_bal_list = []
            for i in json_file_account:
                json_account_bal1 = i['ABAL']  # Getting Account balance from Json service file
                json_account_bal = int(json_account_bal1) / 100
                json_account_bal = ('%f' % json_account_bal).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
                json_bal_list.append(str(json_account_bal))

        # Getting all data from Json Service
        xml_title_list = []
        for j in root.findall("./FCDB_BODY/CUSTACCOUNT/ACCOUNT/ACCOUNTTITLE"):
            xml_acc_title = j.text
            xml_title_list.append(xml_acc_title)

        xml_type_list = []
        for k in root.findall("./FCDB_BODY/CUSTACCOUNT/ACCOUNT/ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL"):
            xml_acc_type = k.text
            xml_type_list.append(xml_acc_type)

        xml_desc_list = []
        for l in root.findall("./FCDB_BODY/CUSTACCOUNT/ACCOUNT/ACCPRDDESC"):
            xml_acc_desc = l.text
            xml_desc_list.append(xml_acc_desc)

        xml_bal_list = []
        for m in root.findall("./FCDB_BODY/CUSTACCOUNT/ACCOUNT/BAL_AVAIL"):
            xml_acc_bal = float(m.text)
            xml_acc_bal = ('%f' % xml_acc_bal).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
            xml_bal_list.append(xml_acc_bal)

        # Checks for Account Number,Title, Type, Description and Balance
        acc_check = [[x for x in xml_acc_no if x not in json_accounts_list],
                     [x for x in json_accounts_list if x not in xml_acc_no]]
        if len(acc_check[0]) or len(acc_check[1]):
            if len(acc_check[0]):
                print("Accounts which are unmatched in XML are ", acc_check[0])

            if len(acc_check[1]):
                print("Accounts which are unmatched in JSON are ", acc_check[1])
        else:
            print("No Unmatched Accounts found")

        title_check = [[y for y in xml_title_list if y not in json_title_list],
                       [y for y in json_title_list if y not in xml_title_list]]
        if len(title_check[0]) or len(title_check[1]):
            if len(title_check[0]):
                print("Title which are unmatched in XML are ", title_check[0])

            if len(title_check[1]):
                print("Title which are unmatched in JSON are ", title_check[1])
        else:
            print("No Unmatched Title found")

        type_check = [[z for z in xml_type_list if z not in json_type_list],
                      [z for z in json_type_list if z not in xml_type_list]]
        if len(type_check[0]) or len(type_check[1]):
            if len(type_check[0]):
                print("Type which are unmatched in XML are ", type_check[0])

            if len(type_check[1]):
                print("Type which are unmatched in JSON are ", type_check[1])
        else:
            print("No Unmatched type found")

        desc_check = [[q for q in xml_desc_list if q not in json_desc_list],
                      [q for q in json_desc_list if q not in xml_desc_list]]
        if len(desc_check[0]) or len(title_check[1]):
            if len(desc_check[0]):
                print("Description which are unmatched in XML are ", desc_check[0])

            if len(desc_check[1]):
                print("Description which are unmatched in JSON are ", desc_check[1])
        else:
            print("No Unmatched Description found")
        balance_check = [[w for w in xml_bal_list if w not in json_bal_list],
                         [w for w in json_bal_list if w not in xml_bal_list]]
        if len(balance_check[0]) or len(balance_check[1]):
            if len(balance_check[0]):
                print("Balance which are unmatched in XML are ", balance_check[0])

            if len(balance_check[1]):
                print("Balance which are unmatched in JSON are ", balance_check[1])
        else:
            print("No Unmatched Balance found")

        print("-----------------------------------")

    else:
        print("CNIC NOT FOUND in Json Service ")
    print("-----------------------------------")
```

Comment: I would recommend fixing the unclosed string and any other errors that might be present *before* posting.

Comment: I have fix the unclosed string.

Comment: What is "too slow"? Why is it "too slow"? What would be an acceptable speed? How did you measure? How can we as reviewers reproduce the slow execution if you don't provide us dummy data?

Comment: Hi @Roland Illig, Sorry for not providing these details before. I am reading an excel file which contain user's unique identity numbers. Based on these numbers i am performing two requests which gives almost same data but in different formats. I need to compare the data. The issue is, I have a file of 1 million identity numbers which i have to use. Right now for one identity number, the whole program take around 8 seconds, which in total are many number of days to perform all data. I thought maybe code needed review that's why i posted the question here

Comment: @AliKhan a bit late, but can you provide some example data, anything? I would love to take a more in depth look at your program :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## List Comprehension

It doesn't look like you're new to list comprehension. So why do you use it some places but not others? When you get the Account Number/Title/Type from the json service file, you use standard loops. These loops can be reduced to three lines:

```
json_accounts_list = [i['ACC#'] for i in json_file_account]
json_title_list = [i['TITLE'] for i in json_file_account]
json_type_list = [i['STYPE'] for i in json_file_account]
```

This reduction can also be applied to when you get all the data from the json service:

```
xml_title_list = [j.text for j in root.findall("./FCDB_BODY/CUSTACCOUNT/ACCOUNT/ACCOUNTTITLE")]
xml_type_list = [k.text for k in root.findall("./FCDB_BODY/CUSTACCOUNT/ACCOUNT/ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL")]
xml_desc_list = [l.text for l in root.findall("./FCDB_BODY/CUSTACCOUNT/ACCOUNT/ACCPRDDESC")]
```

## String Formatting

This one is personal preference, but can provide some cleanliness to your code:

```
('%f' % json_account_bal).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

can be

```
f"{json_account_bal}".rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

This removes the use of parentheses and looks just a bit neater. This can be applied to other parts of your program as well.

## Functions

Your entire program is enveloped in a for loop. I would recommend splitting parts of your code into functions so you can separate and manage what parts do what.

## Printing

Just a little aside about printing. When you print like `print("Hi ", name)`, there are two spaces between "Hi" and whatever the name is. The print function inserts a space whenever you're printing like this, so a little neater output would be `print("Hi", name)`.

Comment: You can use a neat trick to get all the (JSON) lists in one (and a "half") go: `json_list = [i['ACC#'], i['TITLE'], i['STYPE'] for i in json_file_account]` and then `accounts, titles, stypes = zip(*json_list)`. Maybe something similar is also possible on the XML-side.

Comment: Hi @Linny, Thank you for your help. I have applied all of your suggestions.

Comment: @AlexV it gives me syntax error **expected ',' or ']'** before _for loop_

Comment: @AliKhan Sorry, my bad. Please try `json_list = [(i['ACC#'], i['TITLE'], i['STYPE']) for i in json_file_account]` and then `accounts, titles, stypes = zip(*json_list)`.

Comment: @AlexV Thanks much. It works perfectly :)